# change the background of an item when another item is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to write a code to a HTML page, in which there is a table of values. I want that a click on any row of the table changes the background color of another element, basically just a box, to highlight it amongst the other boxes. I am relatively new to JS, HTML, CSS, so I haven't quite made it work.

Rn, i got the click on the row to actually change the color of the box, but with a couple problems. Only the first row of the table works, and it doesn't change back to the original after i "unclick" it.

Anyone can help? Thanks in advance.

the code i have at the moment is this:

```
<style> 
  #row{
    position:relative;
  }
  
  #sensor{
  width:30px;
  height:22px;
  margin: 0 0 -15px 0;
  background-size:100%;
  background: white;  
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  overflow:hidden;

    border: 1px solid black;
  position:absolute;
  left: 70px; top: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
  }  
  #sensor.clicked {background: greenyellow}
</style>
```

```
<div>
    <table> 
        <tbody>
            <tr id="row">
                <td> various table rows </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

```
 $('#row').on('click', function () {
     $("#sensor").addClass('clicked');

  });
```

```
<div>
                  
 <div id="sensor">CON</div>
                  
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the element with ID `sensor`? (And if you want it to toggle rather than just add, you'll need: https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/ )

Comment: "Only the first row of the table works", do you have multiple rows each with the same ID? IDs must be unique in HTML, use classes if you need to reuse a selector.

Comment: i just updated it, the sensor id is just the box that i want the background to be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following uses a delegated event listener, bound to the parent table ( `id='womble'` ), to intercept `click` events that happen within it and it's child elements.

Because of event propagation you can inspect the `event` to find the element upon which the event was initially triggered and deduce whether it is a table row or table cell etc. From there you can easily toggle the desired change of class for the element with ID `sensor`

If the table has more than one row you would need to use a `class='row'` attribute instead of the ID or, alternatively, use a `dataset` attribute such as `data-id='row'` which is permissable.

Notice that clicking on the same cell twice will toggle both the sensor class and the cell itself whereas clicking on separate cells will only toggle the sensor class.

```js
const tbl = document.getElementById('womble');
const div = document.getElementById('sensor');

tbl.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const item = e.target;

  if (item instanceof HTMLTableRowElement || item instanceof HTMLTableCellElement) {
    div.classList.toggle('clicked');
    item.classList.toggle('active');
  }
});
```

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-collapse: all;
}

td {
  padding: 0.25rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px dashed grey;
  background: white;
  transition: ease-in-out all 250ms;
}

#sensor {
  width: 30px;
  height: 22px;
  margin: 0 0 -15px 0;
  background-size: 100%;
  background: white;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 70px;
  top: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: ease-in-out all 250ms;
}

#sensor.clicked {
  background: greenyellow
}
td.active {
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.1)
}
```

```html
<table id='womble'><!-- name / id chosen at random -->
  <tbody>
    <tr class="row">
      <td> various table rows </td>
      <td> more table data </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td> various table rows </td>
      <td> and some more data </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div id='sensor'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are learning to code and manipulate the DOM try not to rely on jQuery. Here's the outline of a pure JavaScript solution which will work in all modern web browsers.

The [document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) method gets a reference to the HTML table element using its unique id.

The [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method is used to attach a handler function to process `click` events on the table.

Within the handler function there is a guard to check if the element click has the `sensor` class before toggling the `clicked` class on the element.

```js
const tableHandle = document.getElementById("table-id");

tableHandle.addEventListener("click", function(event){
  if (event.target.classList.contains("sensor")) { 
    event.target.classList.toggle("clicked");
  }
});
```

```css
.row {
  position: relative;
}
  
.sensor {
  width: 30px;
  height: 22px;
  margin: 0 0 -15px 0;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-color: blue; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
  left: 70px;
  top: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.sensor.clicked {
  background: greenyellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table id="table-id"> 
    <tbody>
      <tr class="row">
        <td class="sensor"> various table rows </td>
        <td class="sensor"> various table rows </td>
        <td class="sensor"> various table rows </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row">
        <td class="sensor"> various table rows </td>
        <td class="sensor"> various table rows </td>
        <td class="sensor"> various table rows </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row">
        <td class="sensor"> various table rows </td>
        <td class="sensor"> various table rows </td>
        <td class="sensor"> various table rows </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

If you insist on using jQuery, the following snippet will work in place of the JavaScript code.

```
$(".sensor").on("click", function () {
  $(this).toggleClass("clicked");
});
```